# How to make extension method to System.IO.File

Tags: c#, extension-methods

If there is a way, I want to know that the way to make extension method to System.IO.File in c#.

I want to make a method like below.

```
// 'CreateDirectoryAndFile is the method I made
System.IO.File.CreateDirectoryAndFile("path");
```

but I've searched it on google, I can't find the way.

So, I was forced to try to do like below.

```
// I made a FileHelper class for this method.
FileHelper.CreateDirectoryAndFile("path");
```

Isn't there a way to do like this?

Comment: You can't create static extension methods. You can only create extension methods on *instances*. The way you've done it is the only way.

Comment: Oh.... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create extension method for static class.

But, you can create wrapper for `System.IO.File` if you need to 'extend' lot of functionality. Like:

```
public class FileWrapper 
{
   public File CreteFile(string path)
   {
   }

   public File CreateDirectoryAndFile(string path)
   {
   }

   // etc
}
```